# How to handle Unicode (Danish) characters in URLs while sharing on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, unicode

We have an eLearning Portal developed in Danish language. URL of the contents contains some native danish characters. If i open that URL in my browser window it opens perfectly fine. But when I try to share url over facebook. It is showing me error. I tried debugging using Facebook's Link testing [tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). It is showing me error and I am not able to understand what is the root cause.

Here is the link I used for testing

http://www.zanicura.com/ElearningView/2849/Genoptr%C3%A6ning-efter-hjerneskade

It works fine in Browser but Facebook debugger is showing error.

Has anyone tried using Unicode while sharing link on Facebook?

Any information will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the Facebook tool—it's going into an endless UTF-8-encode loop.

You might be able to fix it by replacing the IRI in the page:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.zanicura.com/ElearningView/2849/Genoptræning-efter-hjerneskade">
```

With a proper URI-encoded version (`%C3%A6` instead of `æ`).